# IIS 7 Friendly URL rewrite

Tags: http, iis, url-rewriting, seo

I have seen a thousand examples of this:

```
<rule name="ex1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^article/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="article/{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

Which I can easily get to work. What I am trying to do however is to have www.mydomain.net/test rewrite to www.mydomain.net/test.html which I tried to make work with the config below.

```
<rule name="ex2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately I haven´t had any success and I get a simple 404 on every try. Although, when I test my regex it is successful for anything that I wish to match - e.g. www.mydomain.net/test.

Can anybody provide any insight into why this is?

(Using Win7, IIS7 Ultimate).

Comment: Not sure what works whit the first rule that doesn't with the second? Do you know that when you hit `www.mydomain.net/test` only the path part (here `test`) is matched against the pattern you defined?

Comment: Well, the first rule works as it rewrites www.mydomain.net/article/test to www.mydomain.net/article/test.html which is correct. The second rule, considering the changes applied to the regular expression, I thought would work for www.mydomain.net/test => www.mydomain.net/test.html. Testing the second regular expression returns true for 'test' but not for '/test' or 'www.mydomain.net/test' as you can easily see in the regular expression from the negation ^[^/].

Comment: Ok, got it. So at the end, you want to trigger the rewrite rule only when the requested path doesn't contain a `/` but possibly at the end?

Comment: Correct! Of course - test/ should be ok but not /test.

Answer (score 1):

You might try matching on this instead:

```
"^([^/]+)/?$"
```

And replacing with this:

```
{R:1}.html
```

I'm not certain, but I don't think IIS matches on the leading / so that might be what is tripping up your rewrite.

Example: http://regexr.com?36jiq